# Having trouble fitting an exponential decay model to these data in R:

Tags: r, curve-fitting, exponential

1. ***My problem***: I have about 300 rows of data (more variables than the two attached, but only relevant on my end) and need to predict "xaq" (Y) from "seed_prev_num" (x). Their relationship seems to be an exponential decay, but all my attempts with NLS have yielded alternating errors of *Missing value or an infinity produced* or *singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates.*

- **Note:** there are NO zeros, nulls or infinities in the dataset.
- **The purpose** of this model is to have something that guides business rules in thresholding other models. Right now it is heuristic/best guess for performance and we want to more fully automate that process.
- It is also important that ***I can export the coefficients to give another stakeholder an Excel equation from this model***

Here is the graphical relationship between the two variables:[image]

- I would prefer not to have to remove outliers as they are meaningful to our data, subjectively.

2. **I have tried:** log-transform, multiple starting functions, NLS parameters (max of y and different values for b in the exponential function), spline regression and splitting into "higher" and "lower" datasets to model each separately. The log-transform model performs OK, but loses some power in the middle cases, which unfortunately for our business rules, is where the bulk of our data will be arriving.
3. **Here's some code** output from *dput()* to get you started, please let me know if you have questions below!

```r
structure(list(seed_prev_num = c(2671089.52136, 1723563.978132, 
1519478.513963, 10359757.487541, 435039.876186, 400860.993997, 
4824556.66506, 7345496.18374, 7167489.404247, 1541803.448572, 
802314.685373, 2589889.980437, 1578945.817656, 593092.510586, 
9524646.88053, 1517305.29024, 12332649.496439, 1225895.745565, 
1723563.978132, 4029354.348235, 486209.416573, 2473918.859946, 
2200685.368227, 1687211.87222, 34608587.788775, 127034.804899, 
2174606.683551, 694443.762395, 1297414.562631, 269677.307445), 
    xaq = c(3.140014793, 9.363136176, 10.842283188, 2.495966588, 
    6.017711172, 3.124199113, 3.369492219, 2.702313072, 2.587612668, 
    3.000256279, 2.360256095, 4.987947212, 7.002252252, 16.762824783, 
    2.35521676, 10.671484375, 3.007449177, 7.73650282, 4.812929849, 
    2.976955136, 17.230394149, 4.272320716, 5.298590538, 6.414285714, 
    2.321626944, 9.362363919, 3.303806668, 10.004836415, 8.26450434, 
    5.726739927)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Could you share 1 or 2 of your NLS attempts? Have you tried a regular `lm` on logged data like `lm(log(xaq) ~ log(seed_prev_num), data = your_data)`?

Comment: @GregorThomas yes, thanks for the request. I did fit a log transformed linear regression, and it only yielded an Rsq of about 0.22, which management finds pretty unacceptable so I was looking into more accurate approaches.

Comment: Could you share 1 or 2 of your NLS attempts?

Comment: @GregorThomas This was actually perfect...until I realized I had the variables backward. It was almost a perfect fit for our needs: 

```model_exp <- nls(seed_prev_num ~ a * exp(-b * xaq),
             data = df_1,
             start = list(a = 1, b = 0.01),
             algorithm = "port",
             control = list(maxiter = 100))```

and that fit no problem, but then when I tried to order them correctly: ```model_exp2 <- nls(xaq ~ a * exp(-b * seed_prev_num), data = df_1,
                  start = list(a = max(df_1$xaq), b = -1),
                  algorithm = "port")```

Comment: Your starting value for `b` was about 7 orders of magnitude off from the correct value (and of the wrong sign), which is probably why nothing was working ...

Comment: @BenBolker yes, it was the only value that did not produce the infinity/NA error when evaluating model. I could understand why this would be confusing.

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem?  (If I run the `model_exp2` example you gave with the starting value of `b` set to `2e-7` it works fine ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These all seem to work fine:

### log-linear fit

```r
m1 <- lm(log(xaq) ~ seed_prev_num, dd)
```

This assumes that the deviation is *log-normal*, i.e. that `log(xaq)` is Normally distributed with a constant variance. I don't understand what you mean by "loses some power in the middle cases" ...

### log-link Gaussian GLM

This fits the model `y ~ Normal(exp(a+b*x), sigma)`

```r
m2 <- glm(xaq ~ seed_prev_num,  family = gaussian(link = "log"), dd)
```

### nls with log-link GLM starting values

This fits the *same model*.

```r
m3 <- nls(xaq ~ a*exp(b*seed_prev_num),
          data = dd,
          start = list(a = exp(coef(m2)[1]), b = coef(m2)[2]))
```

These are both TRUE:

```r
all.equal(coef(m2)[["(Intercept)"]], log(coef(m3)[["a"]]), tolerance = 1e-5)
all.equal(coef(m2)[["seed_prev_num"]], coef(m3)[["b"]], tolerance = 1e-5)
```

This trick is probably all you need. It also works if you use the starting values from the log-linear fit (`start = list(a = exp(coef(m1)[1]), b = coef(m1)[2]))`).

### nls with arbitrary starting values but scaled x

I suspect that the primary problem is the scaling of your x variable ...

```r
m4 <- nls(xaq ~ a*exp(b*seed_prev_num/1e7),
          data = dd,
          start = list(a = 1, b = 1))

all.equal(coef(m4)[["b"]]/1e7, coef(m3)[["b"]],
     tolerance = 1e-4)
```

The fits don't get much better: your management may have to live with the fact that these are noisy data.

- I also tried `mgcv::gam` with a log-link Gaussian GLM and a smooth function of `seed_prev_num`, but it collapses back to an exponential fit. In any case, this model would violate your "easy to export coefficients and compute in Excel" rubric.
- a power-exponential model:

```r
m6 <- nls(xaq ~ a*exp(b*(seed_prev_num/1e7)^c),
          data = dd,
          start = list(a = 9, b = -2, c =  1.1)
)
```

does slightly better (increases the squared correlation between predictions and observed, aka one form of R^2, to 0.34) but is *not* a better model according to AIC ...